# Is there any way to shrink the spacing between label elements in Python defined Blender UI?

Tags: python, interface

I'm making an addon right now and I often add little hints to the user in the interface like this. Because I do it often enough, I have a function that places the message in the interface like this:

```
def layout_message(layout, message, context=None, text_alignment='CENTER', icon='INFO'):
    row = layout.row()
    box = row.box()
    if context is None:  # assume width of 45
        text_wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(width=45)
    else:
        # Thanks to: https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/multiline-text-in-blender-interface-panels/
        pixels_per_character = 7
        text_wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper(
            width=context.region.width / pixels_per_character)
    line_list = text_wrapper.wrap(text=message)
    box.alignment = 'CENTER'  # BOX IS ALWAYS CENTERED
    row = box.row()
    row.alignment = 'CENTER'
    row.label(icon=icon)
    for line in line_list:
        row = box.row()
        row.alignment = text_alignment
        row.label(text=line)
```

So, if I call it in a panel draw function with something like:

```
layout_message(layout, context.active_object.name +
                               " can also select objects from predefined material groups. Material groups can be created in the Material Groups panel.", context)
```

I get this in the panel.

[image]

Is there any way I can shrink the vertical spacing between text label elements?

Thanks!

Comment: Try something like `row = box.row(); row.ui_units_y -= 5`. "5" being a stand-in here for the number of pixel units you want the row to shrink (or grow if you were to something like`row.ui_units_y += 5`). This is just something I fiddle with when I'm trying to do stuff like this, not 100% sure it will work.

Comment: @Jakemoyo Hey, thanks for the suggestion! I tried it and it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Hmm..Maybe try setting the `scale_y` attribute on the box object? rather than the `ui_units_y` on the row. Just spitballing.

Comment: both sclaing and using ui_units seems to offset the next line also